# Extract geometric polygon fron map img

Tags: php, image, geometry, geojson

I am trying to extract a colored polygon from a map img. Lets say for example this img

[image: POLYGON]

Could it be possible to put this img on lets say the top of google map and create some sort of script that could reproduce this polygon using the coordinates from a real map.

I was thinking of using 2 reference points from the img and the actual map, putting them one on top of the other, and extract the polygon by the color that outlines it.

That would be done on PHP.

Comment: May be it is just me but can you clarify... first half of question suggest you want the polygon and second coordinates form some map so which one is it? You have image of polygon and want to extract it (use more saturated colors to select the right pixels and vectorize) or you know the polygon and want to do something (god knows what) in area covering it from another image (google map) ?

Comment: Ya, I wasnt clear enough. Basically I'm trying to georeference this image or spatial adjust this polygon to a web CRS such as google map. Its from a pdf so I can basically convert it into dxf or an img and from what I have found online, I can try to snap the dxf to an actual map to georeference or convert the pdf to an svg and then create a script to parse the svg to geojson. However, by parsing the svg to geojson, I would use 0,0 coord as the reference point. (http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/02/11/from-svg-to-geo-coordinates-a-complete-guide/) The end goal is to obtain a geoJson polygon.

Comment: so as I see it you need to find the polygon shape in your map (huge ammount of work and knowledge needed for this task) and then obtain the coordinates from it. Do you have API to get the pixel coordinates in map coordinate system?  do you have API to pan,zoom the map? how much user input there will be (user do the matching ?) if the map is just static image then do you have the corner coordinates? are they linear scale?